# Transforming in Pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

| Index | E_Id | P_Id | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 701 | 9002 | 2021 |
| 122 | 701 | 9001 | 2019 |
| 123 | 702 | 9002 | 2021 |
| 124 | 702 | 9002 | 2019 |
| 125 | 703 | 9001 | 2021 |
| 126 | 704 | 9002 | 2019 |
| 127 | 704 | 9003 | 2019 |

Now I want to Create another DataFrame groupedby E_Id
But I want to Count the number of rows against each P_Id call it 'x', and then sum of 'x' for whoever is linked with each E_Id

So

| E_Id | TotalOfPIds |
| --- | --- |
| 701 | 6 |

Can anyone help me?

As an intermediary step, I did this:

`data['_Pid_Total'] = data.groupby('P_Id')[['P_Id']].transform('count')`

And then for single E_Id it works like this:

`data.loc[data['E_Id'] == '701', ['E_Id', 'P_Id', '_Pid_Total']].groupby(['E_Id', 'P_Id']).first().sum()` returning a single integer. However I want to use this in Transform method or just do it for entire DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for an interesting question. My approach is:

1. You creates a `df1` with unique combination of E_id and P_id
2. Create `df2` to count number of unique occur of P_id
3. Merge `df1` and `df2`, then use `groupby` with `sum`

I modify your sample a bit

```
# Dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({'e':[701, 701,701,701, 701, 701,702,702,703,704, 704, 704],
                   'p':[9002, 9002, 9002, 9002, 9001, 9003, 9002, 9002, 9001, 9002, 9003, 9001]})

# Step 1: Unique combination
df1 = df.groupby(['e', 'p']).count().reset_index()

# Step 2: Count Number of occurs for each unique value P_id
df2 = df.groupby('p').count().reset_index().rename(columns={'e':'val'})

# Step 3: Merge then use groupby and sum
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['p'], how='left')
df3.groupby('e')[['val']].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: This is Perfect. Thank you so much. Only thing which I still need is that I need it for all the E_Id even if there is no val. I achieved that by saving the df3.groupby in another df4 and then merging df with my summarydf which has all E_id. It's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to total sum of P_Ids found in each group:

```py
out = (
    df.groupby("E_Id")
    .apply(lambda x: df["P_Id"].isin(x["P_Id"]).sum())
    .to_frame(name="TotalOfPIds")
    .reset_index()
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   E_Id  TotalOfPIds
0   701            6
1   702            4
2   703            2
3   704            5
```